# showing uiview controller as a pop up

Tags: swift, popup

[image]My current viewController is in black color (this should be black as per my requirement). I am presenting another viewcontroller as a popup.
This controller has a default view which i set is as clear color, taken another view on top of default view which has background  color as black and set it alpha as .6 and top of it taken tableview which has background as white. My problem is pop up is showing properly but since my source view controller view's color is black so my popup tableview color is also showing effect of this

Comment: Add the code you've tried so far.

Comment: its all in storyboard.

Answer (score 3):

> Add this code snippet from where you want to lunch popup.

```
    var helpView = UIStoryboard(name: "MainStoryboard", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as? YourViewControllerClass

    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow
    helpView.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.0/255.0, green: 0.0/255.0, blue: 0.0/255.0, alpha: 0.6)
    helpView.view.frame = (window?.frame)!
    window?.addSubview(helpView.view)
    window?.rootViewController?.addChildViewController(helpView)

    helpView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

> Add this code snippet on the popup close button action.

```
    self.view.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Comment: helpView is variable for UIViewController which you want to add as popup.